# httpresponse vs httprequest

Tags: .net, asp.net

I am currently working with the response/request objects when I realized I know next to nothing about them. ***Can someone enlighten me and point me to some documentation on what exactly they are.***

My understanding is the httprequest object is the actual request from a client, and contains all information about the request and client.

My understanding of the httpresponse contains the html markup and all information on how to get the markup to the clients.

This seems pretty rudimentary/incorrect. ***Can you correct this lack of knowledge thank you very much.***

[HttpResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.aspx)

[HttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx)

Comment: Seems such a simple topic, I was sure that i was way off. Since there really isn't an answer to the question do i just mark the first one as the answer and move on?

Comment: Mark the least ridiculous answer as correct - Teoman's and go on.  I was just releasing steam and clearing my mind so I can get back to coding, where I actually communicate clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got it right.  That's the simplest, most accurate way of putting it I could come up with.  It all has to do with where the current communication burst is originating from, as opposed to who initiated the communication session.

Think of a phone call.

> If I were to call you, when I say "Hello" (the "Request") you say
>   "Hello" in return (The response).  Then you ask "Who is this"
>   (request).
>
> I reply, "That nut-job on StackOverflow that actually thought a phone
>   conversation example would make sense." (response).
>
> I then say' How's it going". (Request) You hang up because you really
>   don't know me from Adam.  The phone gives a dial tone indicating the
>   communication session is ended. (http error)

There is more to learn of course, but for the basics, the request and response are simply communications between machines.

There are different types of requests (get, put, etc) but in all cases, the response is just how the other end replies back, whether it's with binary data (images, files, etc), html, or an error code.

That's for a Request/response in general, which is common in other communication protocols, not just http.  As for an httpRequest and httpResponse, these are just .Net framweork objects that abstract away the details of reading the raw http data.

Here's a bit of documentation and explanation that's a bit less silly: http://www.garshol.priv.no/download/text/http-tut.html

Answer (score 2):

That is actually correct. HttpRequest asks for a resource on the server, which may happen to be an .html document full with html markup (which is effectively the response).